# Como puedo instalar un paquete de Python en Visual?

Tags: python, plugin

Pongo esta pregunta por que ya no se donde ir, aunque se como instalar un paquete desde la terminal o desde el CMD y ya tengo instalados los paquetetes como por Ej: numpy , matplotlib , pygame.No me lo deja ejecutar y me indica esta linea de codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no estaria sabiendo que hacer , les agradeceria mucho una ayudar.

Comment: Has probado con `Anaconda` ? Es bastante sencillo, y se instalan los paquetes mediante `pip`. Así mismo, si necesitas un entorno virtual (`venv`) donde instalar ciertos paquetes solo para ese entorno, puedes hacerlo también. Una vez lo tengas prueba en `anaconda prompt`, `pip install numpy`,  `python` para ejecutar ahi mismo algo, y `import numpy as np`, y ver qué pasa.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Es posible que no tengas `numpy` instalado en la version de python que Visual está utilizando (En caso de que tengas diferentes versiones)

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

Si la versión que aparece impresa es Anaconda, entonces ya debe tener `numpy` instalado y si no lo reconoce tendrías que reinstalar. Si aparece otra versión entonces podrías revisar si la versión que ejecutas desde tu terminal es igual a la que esta utilizando Visual

Por defecto Visual utiliza la primera versión de python que aparece en tu variable de entorno (PATH). Para revisar esto puedes poner en tu terminal

Para windows:

```
echo %path%
```

Para linux:

```
echo $PATH
```

Revisa qué versión de python aparece primero y esa será la que utiliza visual

Adicionalmente, puedes configurar en visual el intérprete que va a utilizar para python, teclea `Ctrl+Shift+P` y escribe `Python: Select Interpreter` y selecciona el intérprete que desees

Comment: Muchass gracias.

Solo tenia que cambiar la version en la cual se estaba ejecutando

Comment: @MatiasDIAZDEOTAZU, si te sirvió alguna de las respuestas por favor acéptala. Si encontraste otra solución, escríbela como respuesta y acéptala. De esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios con la misma pregunta, al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas