# Como importar librerías Jira en Netbeans

Tags: java, python, netbeans, jira

anteriormente no podía ejecutar archivos de python en Java con argumentos. Ya pude realizar esa acción, el problema ahora es que en Netbeans obtengo esto en la salida:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ruta_del_script_python, line 4, in <module>
from jira import JIRA
ImportError: No module named jira
```

Si ejecuto en el shell si manda la salida de manera correcta, pero en Netbeans dice que no se puede importar el modulo de Jira cuando si esta instalado.

Comment: Buen día, es posible que tengas una versión diferente instalada en netbeans, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/515701/como-puedo-instalar-un-paquete-de-python-en-visual/515743#515743) hay una pregunta similar, aunque es para Visual, el procedimiento es el mismo. Revisa que tu versión en Netbeans y en Shell sea la misma. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que poner la ruta completa del intreprete a usar, ya que por lo que entiendo Netbeans usa por defecto la versión 2.7 que viene instala en Mac. La librería Jira solo es soportada en Python versión 3.5 o superior.

Saludos!!!